# Did Thor actually pulverize Sokovia with brute force?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

I was having an argument with a fellow. He claimed that Thor destroyed Sokovia with his mighty Mjolnir and brute force, while I think that the Vibranium spire did the impossible as it amplified Thor's blunt force by a lot (don't know the actual computation).

I think that it's quite like the impact caused by Mjolnir hitting Cap's shield. Although we've seen him destroy a lot just with Mjolnir: for instance, when he fought Malekith in Thor: The Dark World, or when he fought the Chitauri in The Avengers (and I mean the Leviathan that he took down solo with his thunder at the portal's opening). But those feats are nothing compared to Sokovia's utter demise.

So, is Thor alone responsible for such destruction or did the Vibranium spire play the vital role in it?

Comment: `don't know the actual computation` C'mon man, lift up your game!

Answer (score 22):

3 things caused Sokovia's destruction:

1. The vibranium spire.
2. Thor's lightning, applied to the top.
3. Iron Man's blast, applied to the bottom.

They somehow combined to destroy Sokovia.  So no, Thor alone did not destroy Sokovia.  His strike was part of a coordinated one with Iron Man.

> Tony - I got it. Create a heat seal.  I could supercharge the spire from below.
>
> FRIDAY - Running numbers.  A heat seal could work with enough power.
>
> Tony - Thor, I've got a plan!

Comment: "By our powers combined..."

Comment: If you listen to Iron Man & F.R.I.D.A.Y.'s dialogue, I think they explain that the energy from the device is what's going to cause the most damage, and Thor's merely the trigger.

Comment: That's exactly what I assessed. I just needed confirmation. thanks.

Comment: Well-reasoned!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thor was helped by the vibrations in the vibranium, but vibranium is just a metal. The power is Thor's. Here is the dialogue to explain what happened:

> FRIDAY: The anti-gravs are rigged to flip. Touch them, they'll go full reverse thrust. The city's not coming down slow.
>
> STARK : Spire is vibranium. If I get Thor to hit it...
>
> FRIDAY : It will crack. That's not enough. The impact would still be devastating.

Ultron raised Sokovia into the sky in order for the anti-gravs to flip and go into reverse thrust, sending the city back to Earth to destroy all human life. If Stark gets Thor to hit the spire, the city/land mass will crack but that's not enough because huge chunks will still rain down on Earth and cause devastation.

> STARK: Maybe if we can cap the other end. Keep the atomic action doubling back.
>
> FRIDAY: That could vaporize the city & everyone on it..

If Stark blocks the power of Thor's strike on the other end (the bottom of the city because Thor is at the top), then the power from the strike will double back upward and vaporize the city. Without the cap, Thor's strike would have just cracked the city and the power from the strike would dissipate outward into the air after that. Stark creates a cap that reverberates that power back up, preventing that dispersion and making it more effective, but it's still Thor's power.

> STARK : I got it. Create a heat seal. I could supercharge the spire from below.
>
> FRIDAY Running numbers
>
> FRIDAY : A heat seal could work with enough power.
>
> STARK: Thor, I got a plan.

The heat seal is the cap Stark creates to bounce the power back up to vaporize the city. Thor hits the vibranium, again which is just metal. The vibrations from the vibranium go downward starting the destruction of the city, hit Stark's heat shield and reverberated back up, completing destruction of the city. It was all Thor channeling the power to destroy the city. Stark merely kept all that energy within the system to maximize its impact.

Answer (score -1):

I think yes and no.
Yes thor did destroy it simply because tony starks supercharging the spire simply heated the vibranium and anyone who knows metal knows that heat weakens metal. Now vibranium is a very strong metal so the force of mjolnir wasnt a trigger it was the real thing but with assistance the lightning was the icing on the cake. Please be reminded the amount of force mjolnir has is simply predicated and the amount of force applied per each swing. For example the hit thor gave to the hulk was a lot more powerful than the hit he gave to iron man simply because of how hard he swung. If you watch both fights carefully. It's also stated by him in one of trailers of age of ultron saying "it's all in the swing."